# My Fibonacci Formula (with combinatorics)

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I'm a high school student, and was playing around with pascals triangle. and ended up taking (weird) diagonals. And I saw Fibonacci numbers, from the sum of the diagonals.

Pascall's triangle is just combinatorics. So I made a formula. I said that the nth Fibonacci number starts at 0. So F(0) = 1, F(1) = 1, F(2) = 2, F(3) = 3, F(4) = 5,...

My sum is this:
$F(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{floor(n/2)} {n-k\choose k}$

This means each diagonal wil lhave floor(n/2)+1 terms.

So $F(0) = {0\choose 0} = 1$
$F(1) = {1\choose 0} = 1$
$F(2) = {2\choose 0} + {1\choose 1} = 2$.....

I put together a python program that does this, and it seems to work.

Have I done something wrong?

What steps should I go through to prove it?

I don't know much maths stuff. Is this already a commonly known formula?

Thanks.

Comment: You've done everything right, and this formula is indeed one of the most classical properties of the Fibonacci numbers. See, e.g., Proposition 1.3.32 in [my *Enumerative Combinatorics* notes](https://darijgrinberg.gitlab.io/t/19fco/n/n.pdf), but equally well most other textbooks on that subject. (Your Fibonacci numbers start one step before mine, so your $F(n)$ is my $f_{n+1}$.)

Comment: This is great to figure out on your own.  Minor note: In the future, Mathstackexchange is probably a better place to start with this sort of question, and bring it over here if people there can't answer it. (But be proud of finding this pattern. Noticing things like this is exactly what math is all about!)

Comment: While this question is not appropriate for this site, I do second JoshuaZ's comment.